# find a tag that contains the window.location.href

Tags: jquery, href, window.location

In order to replace the text that displays the language on my page, 
I want to find the 'a' tag that contains the window.location.href url and set its text as the current language text

I've tried doing: a[href=window.location.href]
but it doesn't work

```
var href = window.location.href;
var currentLangVal = jQuery('.countrySelector a[href=href ]').text();
jQuery('.language-display').text(currentLangVal);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is String Concatenation, in this case, as you want the *value* of the `href` variable, and not `"href"` itself.

```
var href = window.location.href;
var currentLangVal = jQuery('.countrySelector a[href="' + href + '"]').text();
jQuery('.language-display').text(currentLangVal);
```